# How to Rank assets in Portfolio?

Tags: portfolio-management, modern-portfolio-theory

I am working on active equity Portfolio. I have total 30 securities in my Portfolio. Can someone please guide me how can I rank those assets in my portfolio.

```
Should I rank them on their return?
```

`If yes,then how to decide the investment exposure to single asset.`

Thanks

Comment: People have written complete books about this, so it's too broad.

Comment: @ Bob ; Books are very well written. I am looking for an example if someone applied using R or have excel with all formulas...

Comment: I agree, I recommend you study those books well. As it stands this question is too broad.

Comment: Bob request you to do not put the question on hold...allow others to answer the question..

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38462/discussion-on-question-by-atul-agarawal-how-to-rank-assets-in-portfolio).

Comment: I will edit the question to make it answerable.